# "Permission denied (publickey)." error when trying to ssh into server

Tags: ssh, authentication, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to a server via SSH. I am getting the following log from using the command: `ssh -vvvT ubuntu@ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Please could someone help me debug this log as I am getting no where with it.

```
 5742:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvvT ubuntu@ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [176.34.121.133] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" from file "/home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 59:c4:29:87:87:50:f7:eb:fb:ea:2a:39:8b:07:1a:33
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" from file "/home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "176.34.121.133" from file "/home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/karl/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa (0xb7f68a18)
debug2: key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp a2:34:c1:e2:9c:18:e3:46:8b:96:46:f3:59:4b:5f:cc
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA a2:34:c1:e2:9c:18:e3:46:8b:96:46:f3:59:4b:5f:cc
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
5742:~/.ssh$
```

Comment: your public key is not in the server...

Comment: maniat1k - please can you confirm the line from the log which leads you to this conclusion

Comment: read the end of the debug... `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/karl/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/karl/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: So why am I getting three different answers here? You are saying my public key is not on server. Another answer below says its permissions. Then another answer refers to authorised keys file

Comment: your private key checks agaisnt your public key on the server inside a file called autorised_keys check that. like @Terry Wang said in his answer first make sure you copy the public ...

Comment: read this> https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dhsu/ssh_public_key_howto.html

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you copy the public key to the SSH Host.

Show us the contents of `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If public key is in place, make sure on the ssh host

1. permission of the ~/.ssh folder is 700 (could be even tighter)
2. `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is 600

And try again.

If still **NO** luck, stop the sshd on host `service ssh stop` and start it in the foreground in debug mode

`/usr/sbin/sshd -Dd`

Try to ssh to the host with `-v` and see what the output is. Most likely this is a folder/file permission issue.

Comment: hey I don't have an authorised_keys folder set up. Is this the problem?

Comment: This is a file, you definitely need it in place to make public key authentication work. You can use `ssh-copy-id -i identity_file ubuntu@ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` to get it done easily.

Comment: Terry, where should that file go? When I try to run the command,I get an error msg - No identities found

Comment: The identity file is the public key, AWS will provide you a private key in PEM format, to get the public key out of it, you need to run `openssl rsa -in you_private_pem -pubout -out public.key` and then copy the public key to the host properly.

Comment: Terry, please could you provide a link describing this procedure please

Comment: `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/public.pub ubuntu@ec2-176-34-121-133.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` should work. @bosra you need to refer to AWS documentations => http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html